# Can someone do another Masters in Canada if you already have a Masters and PhD from the UK?

Tags: postdocs, education, lecturer, learning, lecture-teaching-method

Can someone do another Masters in Canada if you already have a Masters and PhD from the UK?

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: How different would the subject of the new Masters be from the old one and the PhD?

Comment: Many thank you Azor.                                                                                        
Change of profession-the PhD really didn't provide me with the  opportunity I wanted into my teaching career- So, i am thinking of doing Masters in Education  that may allow me into teaching along the process of the programme and after the programme

Comment: partricia- The My First Masters is in environment- But i really want to get into teaching thats why i want to do the masters- BUT, the main reason why i am asking is from immigration perspectives - if Canadian immigration would allow an international person do that

Comment: I don't know if it is the same in Canada, but in the US, an  EDU masters is more directed at pre-college teaching. There are many specialties within it, however.

Answer (score 1):

I know a lecturer in my university who did his Masters and PhD in Computer Science and also has a Masters in soil science. So yes, you could do any number of Masters you want.  I doubt immigration really cares about your background. If you have admission and support letter from a Canadian university, you should be able to get a visa. And if you are paying fees for your Masters it is unlikely you will have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can study for a second masters, but funding may have different conditions.

I know several people with 2 masters and they did them for their own reasons.

Comment: 2 downvoters who obviously don’t have a masters...